# Recalling Indexed time series data that has randomized "sub" data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been unsuccessful thus far in my efforts using a combination of INDEX(), MATCH(), VLOOKUP(), and OFFSET() functions so far and was looking for some help. I have attached a picture with a sample of the larger dataset that I am working as I am trying to have the table on the right hand side recall the proper data from each time series on the left hand side - I have hardcoded a sample of the desired outputs but doing this from the larger data sample won't be time efficient. My efforts using the aforementioned functions have been futile so far as the data is not standardized alphabetically which the creates problems.

Data set

[image]

Comment: very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794205/three-dimensional-lookup-using-index-match

Answer (score 0):

we could find the position of your date and then build a new range using `Index():Index()`, which we can the use within VLookup.

I'm thinking this way:

```
=VLOOKUP(F$3,INDEX($B$3:$B$15,MATCH($E4,$B$3:$B$15,0)+1):INDEX($C$3:$C$15,MATCH($E4,$B$3:$B$15,0)+5),2,0)
```

Data on the left starts in B3, and table on the right starts in E3 in this particular case.